# cannot keep backslash in string in ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slash

I have a string in my ruby code which ends with a backslash:

```
acc.secret_key = "ASJSJJDSJFJJFFJJFJF\"
acc.save
```

Above is the code snippet, when I try to save it using Active record I get an error, I tried adding another slash that is

```
acc.secret_key = "ASJSJJDSJFJJFFJJFJF\\"
acc.save
```

But now I have two slashes in the DB. What am I missing? THanks a lot.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I dont get an error but I have two slashes in the DB and if I dont do anything and just keep "ASJSJJDSJFJJFFJJFJF\" I get a syntax error

Comment: The two slashes in the db are the result of it escaping the backslash (using another backslash). Try using single quotes as Dave Newton suggests, and there should still be two showing up in the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing this in the console?  If thats the case you're just seeing the escaping not two actual backslashes.

```
string = "1234\\" 
# => "1234\\"
string.length 
# => 5 (if there were two \\'s the length would be 6)
string 
# => "1234\\"
puts string
# 1234\
# => nil
```

If you look up a record with an escaped backslash in your db console you should see one backslash.

```
tests_development=> select * from tests WHERE tests.id = 1;
 id |      name       |         created_at         |         updated_at         | public 
----+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------
  1 | this is a test\ | 2013-02-05 21:44:12.339854 | 2013-02-05 21:44:12.339854 | t
(1 row)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
acc.secret_key = "ASJSJJDSJFJJFFJJFJF//".to_string
acc.save
```

this will push the string with the backshash into the database

Comment: I'm afraid this won't do anything... the string literal is already a string.

Comment: `acc.secret_key = "ASJSJJDSJFJJFFJJFJF//".to_string`  try with this