# RAILS JSON keep backslash in string

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this line in my view form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "ng_b2b_configuration[value][endpoints][][patterns][]", raw(".+\\\\.runsheet\\\\..+") %>
```

it will produce the result:

```
"patterns":[".+\\.runsheet\\..+"]
```

which is not the one that i really want. **My question** is how to keep the backslash after save in my db?

This is exactly what i want: `"patterns":[".+\.runsheet\..+”]`

I've try with this: `<%= hidden_field_tag "ng_b2b_configuration[value][endpoints][][patterns][]", raw(".+\\\\.runsheet\\\\..+"), class: "val_runsheet_all" %>` and the result: `"patterns":[\".+\\.runsheet\\..+\”]`

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the html output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ng_b2b_configuration[value][endpoints][][patterns][]" id="ng_b2b_configuration_value_endpoints__patterns_" value=".+\.runsheet\..+">
```

Comment: But `".+\.runsheet\..+"` in Ruby (i.e. ERB) is just a complicated way of saying `'.+.runsheet..+'` so how does that end up the result you're seeing? Might be helpful to include what the `<input type="hidden">` looks like in your HTML and what the logs say you're getting in `params`. And inside a double quoted Ruby string, `\\.` a single backslash followed by a period.

Comment: @muistooshort ops sorry. i edit my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value=".+\.runsheet\..+"` in the HTML *will* end up as `'.+\.runsheet\..+'` in Ruby so you're being confused somewhere. Nothing you do will (without trickery) will give you a string like:

```
".+\.runsheet\..+"
```

in Ruby or JSON. Backslashes have special meaning in both Ruby double quoted strings and JSON formatted strings. Neither one needs a backslash to escape a `.` so neither will put it there. But because `\` has a special meaning as an escape character in both Ruby double quoted strings and JSON, a single `\` will look like `\\` because both have to escape the special mean of `\` by, well, escaping the escape character.

Go into `irb` and say:

```
puts ".+\.runsheet\..+"
```

and see what you get. Then say:

```
puts ".+\\.runsheet\\..+"
```

and see what you get. The first will give you:

```
.+.runsheet..+
```

and the second:

```
.+\.runsheet\..+
```

Then you can throw in some `to_json` calls (again using `puts` to see the results so that you avoid the escaping that `inspect` will use) and you'll see similar things happening.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. now understood about the double backslashes which is not actual backslash, it just there as escape things. also got the information from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714081/cannot-keep-backslash-in-string-in-ruby-code